# Почему не работает код? Пытаюсь вывести данные из таблицы mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
        $products = $db->query("SELECT name, pricerub FROM products");
        $product = [];
        while ($row = $products->fetch_array()) {
            $product[] = [
                'name' => $row['name'],
                'pricerub' => $row['pricerub']
            ];
        }
        $bot->sendMessage($chat_id,
'Товары:
'.implode("\n", $product['name']).'('.implode("\n", $product['pricerub']).')'.
'

Введите стоимость товара который хотите купить');
```

Как вывести название товара и его стоимость?

Answer (score 1):

```
    $products = $db->query("SELECT name, description, pricerub, priceusd FROM products");
    $product = '';
    while ($row = $products->fetch_array()) {
        $product .= $row['name']." (".$row['description'].") — ".$row['pricerub']."₽"." (".$row['priceusd']."$)\n";
    }
    $bot->sendMessage($chat_id,
```

'Товары:
'.$product.
'

Введите стоимость товара который хотите купить');